# Difference between methods of defining JavaScript 'classes'

Tags: javascript, prototype, function-prototypes

What's the difference between these two method of defining a 'class' in JavaScript?

#### Method One

Define method within the constructor:

```
function MyClass()
{
    this.foo = function() { console.log('hello world!'); };
}
```

#### Method Two

Define method on the prototype:

```
function MyClass()
{}

MyClass.prototype.foo = function() { console.log('hello world!'); };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first will create a new function object on each instantiation of your object, the second will assign a reference to a prototype method to each instance. In short: the second is more efficient, because all instances will share a single function object.

That's just the logic of a prototype chain, you can *try* and access anything via any object:

```
var objLiteral = {foo:'bar'};
```

When accessing `objLiteral.foo` JS will first look at the properties that the object itself has defined, and return the value if it is found. If JS can't find the property on the object itself, it'll check the object's prototype, hence:

```
objLiteral.valueOf();//method defined @Object.prototype
objLiteral.valueOf === Object.prototype.valueOf //true
```

But when you use your first method:

```
function SomeConstructor()
{
    this.methd = function()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
var f = new SomeConstructor();
var g = new SomeConstructor();
f.methd === g.methd;//FALSE!
```

That shows that we're dealing with 2 separate function objects. Move the function definition to the prototype and `f.methd === g.methd;` will be true:

```
function SomeConstructor()
{
}
SomeConstructor.prototype.methd = function()
{
    return true;
}
var f = new SomeConstructor();
var g = new SomeConstructor();
f.methd === g.methd;//true!
```

In response to your comment:

Defining a method on a prototype-level allows you to change a method for a specific task, and then *"reset"* it back to it's default behaviour. Suppose you're in a function that's creating an AJAX request:

```
someObject.toString = function(){ return JSON.stringify(this);}
//when concatinating this object you'll get its json string
//do a lot of stuff
delete (someObject.toString);
```

Again JS will check if the object has the `toString` property defined *on itself*, which it has. So JS will delete the function you've assigned to the `toString` property. Next time the `toString` will be invoked, JS will start scanning the prototype chain all over again, and use the first occurance of the method (in the prototype). Let's clarify:

```
function SomeConstructor()
{
}
SomeConstructor.prototype.methd = function()
{
    return true;
}
var f = new SomeConstructor();
var g = new SomeConstructor();
f.methd = function(){return false;};
g.methd();//returns true, still <-- method is gotten from the prototype
f.methd();//returns false <-- method is defined @ instance level
delete (f.methd);
f.methd();//returns true, f doesn't have the method, but the prototype still does, so JS uses that.
```

Or even better, you can even replace an instance's method by a method from another prototype:

```
f.methd = Object.prototype.valueOf;//for as long as you need
```

the last example is pointless, because f has the `valueOf` method already: its inheritance chain looks like this: `var f ---> SomeConstructor ---> Object`, giving you access to all Object.prototype methods, too! Neat, isn't it?

These are just dummy examples, but I hope you see this is one of those features that make JS an incredibly flexible (sometimes too flexible, I must admit) and expressive language.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Besides performance/memory differences, are there any functional differences that may cause issues if one were to convert between the two approaches?

Comment: Not really, in fact there's an added bonus, I'll edit my answer to explain

Comment: @DrewNoakes: done, I hope I've not been too enthusiastic and chaotic, but this is a good question (+1 for that btw), as it deals with an important feature of JS, but that is often misunderstood by lots of people.

Comment: Your edit is really great too Elias -- it has helped to cement a fundamental aspect of the language that I expect will make certain things seem a little less mystical/confusing in future. I was hoping the answer would be this interesting!

Comment: Oh, yes: when looping with `for...in` the prototype methods _will_ show up, but not when you check for `instanceVar.hasOwnProperty(loopVar)`, but the method name (`hasOwnProperty`) sort of says it all, doesn't it. That method, BTW, is inherited from the Object.prototype, another example of how prototypal inheritance works ;-) -- Credit to Speransky Danil for reminding me of that one. And Thanks for the compliment DrewNoakes, always happy to help. Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

In first case the function will be created for each instance and set to the `foo` property in the object. In second case it is shared function. When you call `obj.prop` then it looks for it in object itself, if it is not there, then it looks for it in `proto` object and so on, it is called `chain of prototypes`.

For example this code provides `foo`:

```
function MyClass() {
  this.foo = function () {};
}

var myVariable = new MyClass();
for (var i in myVariable) if (myVariable.hasOwnProperty(i)) console.log(i);
```

But this not:

```
function MyClass() {
}

MyClass.prototype.foo = function () {};

var myVariable = new MyClass();
for (var i in myVariable) if (myVariable.hasOwnProperty(i)) console.log(i);
```